# Cannot run on selected destination-- Switch to a destination that supports that architecture in order to run the selected software

Tags: architecture, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

So I am currently using CocosBuilder in my project and had to import CCBReader to do so. I pushed the mainmenu.ccbi file in my App Delegate-- the project compiles but does not even run. I get the error: Cannot run on selected destination-- Switch to a destination that supports that architecture in order to run the selected software.

[image]

I believe that i'm correctly implementing CCBReader and Cocos Builder. Am I? Any ideas why it doesn't work?

This is my app delegate code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    // Enable multiple touches
    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:self];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
    //  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
    CCScene* mainScene = [CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"mainmenu.ccbi"];
    [director_ pushScene: mainScene];


    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
//  [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];   // Generates flicker.
    [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

This is for the iPhone simulator.

Comment: what destination? device? simulator? ios version? cocos version? what's the "push" code? If you want an answer don't leave us guessing that much...

Comment: Sorry :( Sorry, Yes, the ios iPhone simulator. I added to my question.

Comment: I think Cocos Builder is being integrated int the code correctly? But I did integrate it as I found to by researching on the internet.

Comment: CB isn't the problem. Check the "build only active architecture" setting (should be NO) and the types of supported architectures. Make sure supported architectures are set to the defaults (armv7 armv7s).

Comment: The setting is NO and the architectures are the defaults. I only got these errors after adding the Cocos Builders ccbi files :/ Not sure why they aren't loading.